# WHM - Mismatched NS records with a GoDaddy domain

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm

I have a WHM at Tilaa and a couple of domains with Godaddy.
I wanted to use pieronanni.it and pieronanni.com so I created a cPanel for pieronanni.it and added an alias for pieronanni.com, and in Godaddy I edited the server domains for pieronanni.com with ns1.pieronanni.com and ns2.pieronanni.com

The problem is that pieronanni.com does not work and this tools gives me [this](https://intodns.com/pieronanni.com) errors, is It a Godaddy configuration or WHM configuration?

I've tried editing the NS for pieronanni.com in WHM with ns1.pieronanni.com. and ns2.pieronanni.com. but nothing happened

Comment: where are you managing your actual DNS records from ? (as in things like the `A` names? is that still with Godaddy?

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking I could see that the nameserver for the domain `pieronanni.it` is using godaddy nameserver. And also I could see that some propagation delay for that domain.

```
ns81.domaincontrol.com
ns82.domaincontrol.com
```

And upon checking we could see that nameserver for that domain `pieronanni.it` is not resolving correctly.

```
ping ns2.pieronanni.com
ping: unknown host ns2.pieronanni.com
```

So first you need to create a custom nameserver.

- Step 1: Point the server IP to your custom nameserve in registrar end.
- Step 2: Add the custom nameserver in your WHM edit DNS zone and point NS1 and NS2 to server IP.

Please check.